# Receiving UDP packets and saving them in a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, udp

So my group and I have been doing an interactive table top tower defense game in Python+Unity, where input is given by IRL towers, that get detected in Python and then sent to Unity through UDP. We've gotten a working solution for detecting x+y and sending them via UDP and splitting them into X and Y, but when Unity receives the locations, it's only the last one that's saved in a variable.

Therefore, we want to save the data in an array, so we can go through the array for instantiating object and its position. However, we have absolutely no clue as to how this goes, and are asking for your help.

Here is the code we have for receiving the X+Y:

```
public void ReceiveData() {
    client = new UdpClient (port);

    while (true) {
        try {
            IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);
            byte[] data = client.Receive(ref anyIP);
            string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            string[] texts = text.Split(',');
            string textX = texts[0];
            string textY = texts[1];

            print (">> " + text);
            lastReceivedUDPPacket = text;
            allReceivedUDPPackets = allReceivedUDPPackets + text;
            xPos = float.Parse(textX, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            yPos = float.Parse(textY, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            print (e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you can help, and thanks in advance :)

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand what your goal is. Do you want to store the historical data you received like allReceivedUDPPackets but in an array?

Comment: @jjj If i detect 5 shapes, i want all 5 values to be saved in a 2D array, rather than being saved in a string variabl, so that i can run a for loop on the array when checking if gameObject location == shape location

Comment: Why not define a 'Coordinate' class with two float fields for the x and y coordinates? You can easily create an instance of this class each time you receive a location message, assign the x and y from the message, and add the object to a list. Iterate over the list with a for-each whenever required.